# Minimum and Maximum in column

Tags: linux, bash, awk

I am try to get the minimum and maximum value from one column but with reference to other.

this is my input file

```
338043.75 2395256.25 36301 38676 1296
338056.25 2395256.25 36301 38677 1296
338068.75 2395256.25 36301 38678 1296
338081.25 2395256.25 36301 38679 1296
338043.75 2395256.25 36302 38676 1296
338056.25 2395256.25 36302 38677 1296
338068.75 2395256.25 36302 38678 1296
338081.25 2395256.25 36302 38679 1296
338043.75 2395256.25 36303 38676 1296
338056.25 2395256.25 36303 38677 1296
338068.75 2395256.25 36303 38678 1296
338081.25 2395256.25 36303 38679 1296
338043.75 2395256.25 36304 38676 1296
338056.25 2395256.25 36304 38677 1296
338068.75 2395256.25 36304 38678 1296
338081.25 2395256.25 36304 38679 1296
338043.75 2395256.25 36305 38676 1296
338056.25 2395256.25 36305 38677 1296
338068.75 2395256.25 36305 38678 1296
338081.25 2395256.25 36305 38679 1296
```

the purpose is to get the minimum and maximum from column 4, when the value in column 3 is the same.

Then my desired output is this

```
338043.75 2395256.25 36301 38676 1296
338081.25 2395256.25 36301 38679 1296
338043.75 2395256.25 36302 38676 1296
338081.25 2395256.25 36302 38679 1296
338043.75 2395256.25 36303 38676 1296
338081.25 2395256.25 36303 38679 1296
338043.75 2395256.25 36304 38676 1296
338081.25 2395256.25 36304 38679 1296
338043.75 2395256.25 36305 38676 1296
338081.25 2395256.25 36305 38679 1296
```

I have tried this code, but it does not works properly to get the desired output.

```
awk     '               {D1=substr($3, 1, 5)
                         D2=substr($4, 6, 5)+0
                        }
         !(D1 in MIN)   {MIN[D1]=D2
                         MAX[D1]=D2
                         next
                        }
          D2 < MIN[D1]  {MIN[D1]=D2}
          D2 > MAX[D1]  {MAX[D1]=D2}
          END           {for (m in MIN) print m, MIN[m], MAX[m]}
        ' file
```

Comment: What does your "undesired" output look like?

Comment: Zak , my code prints only the minimum and maximum in column 4 for each variable in column 3. And that is not what i want. Example 36305 38676 38669

Comment: You need separate arrays to hold the lines: when you set the min for some key, also set the min_line for that key; same for max.

Comment: based on the sample data your `D2=substr($4, 6, 5)+0` will be always zero.  The field length is 5, so the substring starting from 6th position is null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
awk '
    function set_min() { min[$3] = $4; min_line[$3] = $0 }
    function set_max() { max[$3] = $4; max_line[$3] = $0 }
    !($3 in min) { set_min(); set_max() }
    $4 < min[$3] { set_min() }
    $4 > max[$3] { set_max() }
    END {
        for (key in min) {
            print min_line[key]
            print max_line[key]
        }
    }
' file
```

Answer (score 1):

a different take...

```
$ function pick(){ sort -k3,3 -k4,4n"$2" "$1"  | awk '!a[$3]++'; }
$ cat <(pick file) <(pick file r) | sort -k3

338043.75 2395256.25 36301 38676 1296
338081.25 2395256.25 36301 38679 1296
338043.75 2395256.25 36302 38676 1296
338081.25 2395256.25 36302 38679 1296
338043.75 2395256.25 36303 38676 1296
338081.25 2395256.25 36303 38679 1296
338043.75 2395256.25 36304 38676 1296
338081.25 2395256.25 36304 38679 1296
338043.75 2395256.25 36305 38676 1296
338081.25 2395256.25 36305 38679 1296
```

sort the data both ways and pick the first (smallest and largest respectively) with `awk` (an advanced `uniq` substitute).  Merge the results and sort on key as a final touch.